# Strategy to incorporate Likes, while preventing users from "multi-liking" utilizing MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a website that needs to incorporate likes, while preventing any user from liking a post multiple times. I am using React, Express, and MySql. 
On this website, there is a page where a user can view all posts, where each entry includes: (1) the post message, (2) the user who created the post, and (3) how many likes that post might have. This was a trivial SQL Command where I performed the following query:

```
SELECT users.username, posts.message, posts.likes
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts
WHERE users.user_id = posts.post_id
```

With my current implementation, I have a button located on each post, that when clicked will communicate with my backend to **insert** the associated user_id and post_id within my 'likes' table. My vision is that if a user has already liked a certain post, then to show a dislike button, and if the user has not liked a post, to show the like button.

I know I am on the right track with creating a 'likes' table, since I can't have duplicate entries.
**The query I desire is one where I can have a list of all the posts a user has liked as well as the ones they have not liked.** I know this can be obtained with either a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN between the 'posts' table and the 'likes' table. However, with this list of results, how can I distinguish which posts a user has liked and the ones they have not liked, so that when I map() through this list I can easily place a like button if the user has not liked a post or a unlike if the user has not liked the post?

Here is my SQL schema:

```
Users Table (user_id, username, password) //Primary Key: user_id
Posts Table (post_id, message, likes) //Primary Key: post_id 
Likes Table (user_id, post_id) //Primary Keys: user_id, post_id and Foreign Keys: user_id, post_id
```

Comment: “However, with this list of results, how can I distinguish which posts a user has liked and the ones they have not liked..” - from the (LEFT) JOIN. The rows that are “missing” and thus have NULL values on the outer join mean the user has not liked. This can be decorated in the select output clause such as: “case when like_id is null then 0 else 1 end as liked”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join the `likes` to the `posts` on common `post_id` and the ID of the user in question. Then check if `l.user_id IS NOT NULL`. If and only fi it is, then the user liked that post.

```
SELECT p.*,
       l.user_id IS NOT NULL liked
       FROM posts p
            LEFT JOIN likes l
                      ON l.post_id = p.post_id
                         AND l.user_id = ?;
```